# TortoiseSVN - missing files in client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I just deleted two files in the client and when tried to update those two files were missing, but they were in the server.

I tried "cleanup" and then "update" which didn't work. But when I checked out a new version to a different location the files were there.

In what situation this scenario happens? Initially I have "added" files to the server but it happened to be that the server already has those files.

P.S. I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.5.6.

[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/2140/missingfiles.jpg](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/2140/missingfiles.jpg)

***Problem went away when I deleted the whole sub containing folder and did  another "update" under the parent folder. what caused this?***

Thanks,

Answer (score 13):

Right click on the folder where you deleted the files, select revert, the files should appear there with the *Missing* status, select **only those files** and click Ok.

[image: Missing files]

Comment: Just make sure any files with modifications that you want to keep are unchecked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I did see those "missing" files and checked them before dismissed the revert dlg. But when I apply "update" nothing happened inside that folder.

When I "revert" that folder again, "missing" files were gone but only "modified" were left.

Comment: When you revert *missing* files, they are restored back to your working copy, I'm sure the files were restored.

Comment: unfortunately that's not the case. Does it mean I have a broken SVN folder? For details, please refer to the above pic.

Thanks,

Comment: You can then delete them with the SVN delete command if you don't ant them.

Comment: I have the same problem as user124858, that is, CMS's answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I see this a lot with the Subversive plugin in Eclipse and the command line SVN client.
When following HEAD it usually doesn't happen, but when I switch to an earlier revision and back to head I usually lose a file that was added or removed in the mean time.
"svn up folder/" does not restore them, "svn up folder/file" does ("Added").
I didn't see that with earlier subversion versions, to me this seems to be regression in 1.5 or 1.6.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue. I am posting it here to avoid creating an unnecessary duplicate question for a similar problem.
Revert did not work. Cleanup or clear of cache also did not work.

What worked for me was to update to an earlier version, and then updating to the newest version.

Answer (score -1):

I can acknowledge that this issue still exists in TortoiseSVN 1.9.2, Build 28806 - 64 Bit, running on Windows 7.

Even after removing big parts of the directory tree and doing an update afterwards the missing file won't be restored. "svn revert", "svn cleanup" etc. also don't work. But I can restore the file from command line with "svn update dir/missing_file.txt". A simple "svn update dir" didn't work.